# Most efficient way to traverse through a Json Object to collect property values in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to traverse through a Json Object to collect some properties values.
The problem is the returning data varies depending on some input.

```
{
  "id": "<some guid>",
  "messageSummary": "<messageSummary>",
  "messageDetail": null,
  "errorMessage": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "PropertyA": {
        "ErrorCode": null,
        "ErrorMessage": null
      },
      "PropertyB": null,
      "PropertyC": "3723",
 
      "PropertyD": [
        {
          "PropertyE": "<property E Value>",
          "PropertyF": "<property F Value>",
          "ErrorCode": null,
          "ErrorMessage": null
        },
        {
          "PropertyG": "<property G Value>",
          "PropertyH": "<property H Value>",
          "ErrorCode": null,
          "ErrorMessage": null
        }
      ],
      "PropertyI": [
        {
          "PropertyJ": "<property J Value>",
          "PropertyK": "<property K Value>",
          "ErrorCode": null,
          "ErrorMessage": null
        }
      ],
      "PropertyL": [
        {
          "PropertyM": "<property M Value>",
          "PropertyN": "<property N Value>",
          "ErrorCode": null,
          "ErrorMessage": null
        }
      ],
      "Tasks": [],
      "ErrorCode": "-1021",
      "ErrorMessage": "<some error message>"
    }
  ]
}
```

- The data array can be null or empty array
- The objects in the data array may or may not exists.
- ErrorMessage properties in any object in the data array may or may not exists

What I am trying to achieve is collecting all ErrorMessage values in a list of string (including first 'errorMessage' and all other 'ErrorMessage')

Comment: You want a recursive function that returns a dynamical object (a dictionary/map) which represent your json tree. That is what deserializing does. Why not deserialize your json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Newtonsoft JSON.NET, you could parse your JSON into a JObject with `JObject.Parse()` and then apply the following. Unfortunately this is case sensitive:

```
List<string> list = o.SelectTokens("$..ErrorMessage")
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ToString()))
            .Select(y => y.ToString())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: does "$..ErrorMessage" means it is two levels down or does it indicate a recursive search all through the JObject?

Comment: @bugrasitemkar - It's a recursive descent in JSONPath syntax: https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html